# Displayport Sound Delay on Ubuntu 20.04/20.10

Tags: sound, 20.10, displayport

I have decided to try switching to Ubuntu in a dual-boot scenario with Windows 10, and things work perfectly overall, but I have encountered one bug that really ruins the experience. I get my sound from my monitor from the displayport cable that is connected to the GPU, and this works without any issues on Windows, but on Ubuntu I've had two separate issues with it.

The first is that the system would just randomly switch from DisplayPort 3 as a audio output source to Digital Output, something that I fixed through Pavucontrol.

But the other issue, which is just as annoying, is the sound delay. Whenever I resume a video after a minute or two, the video starts, but the audio only starts after a few seconds of silence, making the entire experience be very jarring. I've set the latency in Pavucontrol to 0 but this doesn't fix it. Using Alsamixer to mute all but one of the S/PDIF options seems to help somewhat, but not completely.

I've tried to look around the internet for help, but that only made me even more confused than before, with bug reports of sound delays on HDMI from 2015 and someone suggesting a complicated measure that would have essentially played silent sounds at all times.

Is there anything I can do?

Comment: I am having the same issue. I bought Dell AX510PA today and attached it to my Dell U3014. The monitor is connected to my machine (Dell Precision M4700) through DisplayPort cable. I am using Arch linux, so seems like this is a common issue. Looking forward to an answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Updated**

1. Open `/etc/pulse/default.pa` and comment out the line `load-module module-suspend-on-idle` i.e put # in front of it like `#load-module module-suspend-on-idle` and save the file, do similar thing for `/etc/pulse/system.pa`.
2. Run `pulseaudio -k` to kill pulseaudio daemon and run `pulseaudio --start` to start it again (or you can also run `systemctl --user restart pulseaudio` if `pulseaudio` starts on the boot) .

Your problem should be solved.

Thanks to https://forum.level1techs.com/t/delayed-sound-output-ubuntu-elementary-os-solved/115034

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try to do this and I'll let you know if the issue is fixed!

Comment: It seems to have fixed it for me, thank you very much!

Comment: @AshenPaladin Please see the updated answer.